# How can I convert an ascx usercontrol to an image to be saved on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I have a shipping label ascx control and I need to convert the rendered control to an image and then save it on the server.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible but it would probably be easier to use something like ITextSharp to create a PDF shipping label.

Comment: Should we assume you don't have control over the ASCX control? What properties do it offer if so? But if you do have control over it, have the control provide a method to pull the raw data out of it instead of extracting the image after it is displayed via some WebResource.axd call or whatever it is using.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but you could put an image in the user control and expose image or the path to the page.

```
//option 1: expose the image path
string imageUrl = MyUserControl.ImagePath; 

//option 2: expose the image control
Image img = MyUserControl.SomeImage; //image
```

When you say that you want to save the image on the server, I'm a little confused - isn't the image already on the server, if you're displaying it in the user control? Are you looking to save the image somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really convert an Aspx control into an image; however you can convert a Windows Form's control into an image! You should recreate the control as a windows form (yes this works in web applications), populate the data by exposing the necessary properties "draw" the form to a bitmap. If you prefer Windows Presentation foundation, then you can do the same.

I've had to do the windows form draw to image to create dynamic charts for aspx applications before, and the result is fantastic.